# Different behaviour between python console and python script

Tags: python, console, gtk, pydev

I am experiencing different behaviour on the same code using the python console and a python script.

The code is as follows:

```
import gtk
import webkit
win = gtk.Window()
win.show()
web = webkit.WebView()
win.add(web)
web.show()
web.open("http://www.google.com")
```

When running the code in the python console, the output is a new frame that contains the google main page.

When running the code as a script, the result is a void frame. It closes very fast but even if I use a delay function, the webkit is not added to the frame.

How is it possible?

Furthermore, using PyDev IDE it flags: "unresolved import: gtk",
but if i run the project, the program starts without problem of compilation. is it normal?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add

```
gtk.main()
```

to the end of your script. This starts the `gtk` event loop.

---

```
import gtk
import webkit

class App(object):
    def __init__(self):
        win = gtk.Window()
        win.connect("destroy", self.destroy)
        web = webkit.WebView()
        web.open("http://www.google.com")
        win.add(web)
        web.show()
        win.show()
    def destroy(self, widget, data = None):
        gtk.main_quit()
app = App()
gtk.main()
```

Comment: :D it worked! thank you, have you any idea of why pydev doesn't recognize gtk library but it compile anyway?

Comment: Sorry, I have no experience with pydev.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that the console keeps the python session open, while at the end of the script the program closes.  When the script closes, it takes everything it created with it.

Something to test this theory: if you type "exit" in the console do you see the interface shut down in the same manner?  If so, think of some code (e.g. a pause like a `raw_input`) that will allow the script to stay open.

Good luck!

Comment: ok, i've just tried, and waiting the right time a pop up will appear:
metacity: no response from the application